# Recognize Patterns of images JPG or PNG

Tags: php, image, image-processing, computer-vision, object-recognition

Hello friend I want to recognize and determine the type of object into photo jpg or png with php, for example determine if exists a apple or grapes, or car, or animals into any photo. Please if somebody know about that, because I want to make exactly that.

Regards
Gildus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object recognition in computer vision is an open and ongoing area of research.  There's some good work being done, but we're a long way from being able to extract details about what's in a scene with ease.

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_recognition_(computer_vision)) page has some algorithm names for various approaches if you're curious.

Comment: May I add that even what can be done today is computationally intensive and hence not suited for a scripting language such as PHP?

Comment: An excellent point.  I completely skimmed over the php part since it was piled in with image formats.